# Bootstrap: Content in middle of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple navbar and beneath that I have some links. I want that the links are on the middle of the page. I now have set this margin but that is going to be different depending on the screen. How can I achieve this?

```
<nav class="navbar nabbar-inverse">
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <!--<img src="Logo.png" alt="Logo" class="navbar-brand">-->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.php?pageNr=7">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?pageNr=5">Chemisch Lab</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?pageNr=3">Fysisch Lab</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?pageNr=1">Mechanisch Lab</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mid">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center"><a href="index.php?pageNr=5">
    <h1>Chemisch Lab</h1></a></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center"><a href="index.php?pageNr=3">
    <h1>Fysisch Lab</h1></a></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center"><a href="index.php?pageNr=1">
    <h1>Mechanisch Lab</h1></a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mid {
    margin-top: 15%;
}
```

Here I have a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u6j5cw60/1/

Comment: Can you please make a working fiddle.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u6j5cw60/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('.mid').css('margin-top', function () {
    return ($(window).height() - $(this).height()) / 2
});
```